# Import local function from a module housed in another directory with relative imports in Jupyter Notebook using Python 3

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, relative-import

I have a directory structure similar to the following

```
meta_project
    project1
        __init__.py
        lib
            module.py
            __init__.py
    notebook_folder
        notebook.jpynb
```

When working in `notebook.jpynb` if I try to use a relative import to access a function `function()` in `module.py` with:

```
from ..project1.lib.module import function
```

I get the following error:

```
SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6393744d93ab> in <module>()
----> 1 from ..project1.lib.module import function

SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Is there any way to get this to work using relative imports?

Note, the notebook server is instantiated at the level of the `meta_project` directory, so it should have access to the information in those files.

Note, also, that at least as originally intended `project1` wasn't thought of as a module and therefore does not have an `__init__.py` file, it was just meant as a file-system directory. If the solution to the problem requires treating it as a module and including an `__init__.py` file (even a blank one) that is fine, but doing so is not enough to solve the problem.

I share this directory between machines and relative imports allow me to use the same code everywhere, & I often use notebooks for quick prototyping, so suggestions that involve hacking together absolute paths are unlikely to be helpful.

---

Edit: This is unlike [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3), which talks about relative imports in Python 3 in general and – in particular – running a script from within a package directory. This has to do with working within a jupyter notebook trying to call a function in a local module in another directory which has both different general and particular aspects.

Comment: If `project1` is considered a package then it should also include `__init__` as well

Comment: @baldr, that talks about Python 3 in general and in particular running a script from within a package directory. This has to do with working within a jupyter notebook trying to call a function in a module in another directory. I looked through the answers there before posting this question, if you think it is a duplicate or is already answered please can you point me to the particular answer you think is relevant?

Comment: `project1` isn't intended to be a package, and adding an `__init__.py` doesn't fix anything (the same error is returned). Partially, what I was intending to convey was the differences between the directory structure and the roles the different directories were playing (organization vs. functional). But, if it just wouldn't work without that, I can add the `__init__.py` to the Q.

Comment: And make sure you restart the notebook kernel after all these changes!

Comment: If you are using **VSCODE** you can enable it in the settings:
[VSCODE settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rkAm.png)

Comment: "This is unlike Relative imports in Python 3, which talks about relative imports in Python 3 in general and – in particular – running a script from within a package directory." - It is absolutely the same. The cause is the same - the parent folder isn't recognized as a package, because it hasn't been loaded as one - and the solutions are all the same. Another reason to deprecate this question is that the top/accepted answer is yet another one recommending a cargo-cult `sys.path` hack which is completely unnecessary and masks proper understanding of the problem.

Comment: In particular, it doesn't even answer the question that was actually asked, since it shows how to perform an absolute import rather than a relative import. That should only be considered acceptable if relative imports were impossible here, but they absolutely are possible.

Answer (score 295, accepted):

I had almost the same example as you in [this notebook](https://github.com/qPRC/qPRC/blob/master/notebook/qPRC.ipynb) where I wanted to illustrate the usage of an adjacent module's function in a DRY manner.

My solution was to tell Python of that additional module import path by adding a snippet like this one to the notebook:

```
import os
import sys
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
```

This allows you to import the desired function from the module hierarchy:

```
from project1.lib.module import function
# use the function normally
function(...)
```

Note that it is necessary to add empty `__init__.py` files to *project1/* and *lib/* folders if you don't have them already.

Comment: This solves the problem of being able to import a package using what is more or less a relative location, but only indirectly. I happen to know Matthias Bussonier (@matt on SE) and Yuvi Panda (@yuvi on SE) are developing https://github.com/ipython/ipynb which will address this more directly (e.g., by allowing relative imports using the standard syntax once their package is imported). I'll accept your answer for now, and when their solution is completely ready for others to use I will probably either write an answer on how to use it, or ask one of them to do so.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the empty __init__.py   I'm a python novice and was having trouble getting my classes to import. I was getting module note found errors,  adding empty __init__.py fixed the problem!

Comment: The empty __init__.py file is no longer needed in Python 3.

Comment: FYI: there is a viewer for notebook: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/qPRC/qPRC/blob/master/notebook/qPRC.ipynb

Comment: @CathyQian not at all, package without `__init__.py` is a namespace package. We should stick to regular packages in most cases. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804718/13326361

Answer (score 51):

I use this project structure:

```
my_project
├── nb
│   ├── 20170609-Examine_Database_Requirements.ipynb
│   └── 20170609-Initial_Database_Connection.ipynb
└── my_package
    ├── __init__.py
    └── postgres.py
```

And from a notebook:

```
    In [1]: import os
            os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/location_of/my_project")

    In [2]: from my_package.postgres import database_connection
```

Comment: Thanks. Really horrible the restrictions of this relative imports.

Comment: I too use `chdir` rather than adding to path, since I'm both interested in importing from the main repo as well as interfacing with some files there.

Comment: Sadly, the most hacked thing I do in python.  Yet, I cant find a better solution.

Comment: for simple idempotence (allowing the same cell to run multiple times & get same result): `if os.path.isdir('../lib/'): os.chdir('../lib')` ; or, better, use `../lib/db/` with your `postgres.py` so as not to accidentally chdir up to a higher directory also containing another `lib`.

Comment: I like this solution until I accidentally executed `cd ..` twice.

Comment: I had mixed results with the cd route (i.e. it didn't really work), further, there's no good way to make it idempotent. If this is still a pattern you're using, check out the path.py library, it provides a context manager for changing the working directory helping to make this import idempotent, safe, and runnable without using bash commands.

Comment: idempotency in 2020 ... treat your notebooks as stateless, always restart your kernel

Comment: I strongly discourage this approach. *Nobody* is going to keep a mental map of where they are in the directory path when running code from a notebook.

Comment: @qkhhly it's trivial to run pwd to know where you are. Regardless, as I noted before, your notebooks should be treated as stateless meaning the cd gets run only once, each time to start the kernel. Three years later and I still use this practice.

Answer (score 36):

All other answers here depends on adding code the the notebook(!)

In my opinion is bad practice to hardcode a specific path into the notebook code, or otherwise depend on the location, since this makes it really hard to refactor you code later on. Instead I would recommend you to add the root project folder to PYTHONPATH when starting up your Jupyter notebook server, either directly from the project folder like so

`` env PYTHONPATH=`pwd` jupyter notebook ``

or if you are starting it up from somewhere else, use the absolute path like so

`env PYTHONPATH=/Users/foo/bar/project/ jupyter notebook`

Comment: This is actually the best answer for this question.

Comment: Can't believe I had to scroll down so far to find an answer that didn't involve hardcoding something into the notebooks :-( Thank you!

Comment: This did not work for me. I too was excited to not hardcode relative paths.

Answer (score 21):

So far, the accepted answer has worked best for me. However, my concern has always been that there is a likely scenario where I might refactor the `notebooks` directory into subdirectories, requiring to change the `module_path` in every notebook. I decided to add a python file within each notebook directory to import the required modules.

Thus, having the following project structure:

```
project
|__notebooks
   |__explore
      |__ notebook1.ipynb
      |__ notebook2.ipynb
      |__ project_path.py
   |__ explain
       |__notebook1.ipynb
       |__project_path.py
|__lib
   |__ __init__.py
   |__ module.py
```

I added the file `project_path.py` in each notebook subdirectory (`notebooks/explore` and `notebooks/explain`). This file contains the code for relative imports (from @metakermit):

```
import sys
import os

module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.pardir, os.pardir))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
```

This way, I just need to do relative imports within the `project_path.py` file, and not in the notebooks. The notebooks files would then just need to import `project_path` before importing `lib`. For example in `0.0-notebook.ipynb`:

```
import project_path
import lib
```

The caveat here is that reversing the imports would not work. THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
import lib
import project_path
```

Thus care must be taken during imports.

Comment: A question about your folders. 'Explore' is where you do explorative work? What is the 'explain' folder used for (just wondering about your workflow)

Answer (score 17):

I have just found this pretty solution:

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '..') # add parent folder path where lib folder is
import lib.store_load # store_load is a file on my library folder
```

You just want some functions of that file

```
from lib.store_load import your_function_name
```

If python version >= 3.3 you do not need init.py file in the folder

Comment: I found this very helpful. I'll add that the following modification should be added --> `if ".." not in sys.path: ... sys.path.insert(0,"..")`

Comment: Really like this one, clear and succinct.

Answer (score 9):

If you are working via the Jupyter extension in VS Code, I found that you can now set this path in your `settings.json` file.

```
{
    "jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "/path/to/your/module/root"
}
```

Edit: Or, to set it at your workspace root more generically:

```
{
    "jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I have found that [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) helps solve this issue pretty effectively. Your project structure ends up changing slightly, but the code in your notebook is a bit simpler and consistent across notebooks.

For your project, do a little install.

```
pipenv install python-dotenv
```

Then, project changes to:

```
├── .env (this can be empty)
├── ipynb
│   ├── 20170609-Examine_Database_Requirements.ipynb
│   └── 20170609-Initial_Database_Connection.ipynb
└── lib
    ├── __init__.py
    └── postgres.py
```

And finally, your import changes to:

```
import os
import sys

from dotenv import find_dotenv


sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(find_dotenv()))
```

A +1 for this package is that your notebooks can be several directories deep. python-dotenv will find the closest one in a parent directory and use it. A +2 for this approach is that jupyter will load environment variables from the .env file on startup. Double whammy.

Comment: Very clever solution. Also, [_python-dotenv_ provides a magic command to load the .env vars in the Jupyter/IPython environment](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv#load-env-files-in-ipython). First `%load_ext dotenv`, and then just `%dotenv`.

Comment: Perfect! Added to my personal toolbox of snippets!

Answer (score 4):

Researching this topic myself and having read the answers I recommend using the [path.py library](https://pathpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) since it provides a context manager for changing the current working directory.

You then have something like

```py
import path
if path.Path('../lib').isdir():
    with path.Path('..'):
        import lib
```

Although, you might just omit the `isdir` statement.

Here I'll add print statements to make it easy to follow what's happening

```py
import path
import pandas

print(path.Path.getcwd())
print(path.Path('../lib').isdir())
if path.Path('../lib').isdir():
    with path.Path('..'):
        print(path.Path.getcwd())
        import lib
        print('Success!')
print(path.Path.getcwd())
```

which outputs in this example (where lib is at `/home/jovyan/shared/notebooks/by-team/data-vis/demos/lib`):

```
/home/jovyan/shared/notebooks/by-team/data-vis/demos/custom-chart
/home/jovyan/shared/notebooks/by-team/data-vis/demos
/home/jovyan/shared/notebooks/by-team/data-vis/demos/custom-chart
```

Since the solution uses a context manager, you are guaranteed to go back to your previous working directory, no matter what state your kernel was in before the cell and no matter what exceptions are thrown by importing your library code.

Comment: This will not work in combination with %autoreload, since the module path will not be found at reload time

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents:

```py
import sys
# map the path where the module file is located. In my case it was the desktop
sys.path.append('/Users/John/Desktop')

# Either import the whole mapping module BUT then you have to use the .notation to map the classes like mapping.Shipping()

import mapping #mapping.py is the name of my module file

shipit = mapping.Shipment() #Shipment is the name of the class I need to use in the mapping module

# Or import the specific class from the mapping module
from mapping import Mapping

shipit = Shipment() #Now you don't have to use the .notation
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't understand the solution as I didn't, you have to go as deep to the directory as you need for your specific problem. Solution for this errorr:

> No module named 'your_folder'

My notebook that I work with is in:

`C:\Users\vojte\projects\predicta\EDA\apartments\EDA.ipynb`

I want to import this notebook:

`C:\Users\vojte\projects\functions\functions.ipynb`

I had to modify the solution above by @metakermit to this solution:

```
import os
import sys
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..\..\..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)

from functions import functions as f
```

You can check the `sys.path` for appended directory. In this example this line was appended:

`C:\\Users\\vojte\\projects`

Answer (score 0):

Improving @joshua-cook [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44486700/11671779) in using `cd..`, to make sure that you did not re-run the cell and messing your directory in using `run all` without `restart`, use this code instead:

```
if 'NOTEBOOK_INITIATED_FLAG' not in globals():
    NOTEBOOK_INITIATED_FLAG = True
    %cd ..
%pwd
```

`NOTEBOOK_INITIATED_FLAG` is used as a placeholder that mark that the kernel is already running, thus changing directory is not needed.

And this is the super convoluted boilerplate if you want to work with `jupytext` and run your `.py` file from parent folder:

```
import os
import sys

if 'NOTEBOOK_INITIATED_FLAG' not in globals():
    NOTEBOOK_INITIATED_FLAG = True
    
    try:
        # not in notebook
        module_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)
    except:
        # in notebook
        module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
        %cd ..
        %pwd

    if module_path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(module_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got annoyed so I [wrote a package](https://pypi.org/project/package-root/1.0.0/).

`pip install package_root` and then you can `import package_root # into your PYTHONPATH`.

This works by looking through the call stack to determine which file imported `package_root` and then walking the up directories to find the first directory that is missing an `__init__.py` file.

So in practice, you'll need to add `__init__.py` files to your notebook directories just like you would to get Python packages to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50395128/11996983) that neither requires specifying the parent folder name, nor requires changing the current working directory.

Just update `root_parent_level` with the number of parent levels where relative imports start, and make sure that `__init__.py` exists in each subpackage.

```py
if "PKG" not in globals(): # `PKG` is used just to avoid re-excuting the cell more than once
  root_parent_level = 2
  import importlib, sys, pathlib
  PKG = %pwd
  PKG = pathlib.Path(PKG)
  root = PKG
  full_pkg = f"{root.name}"
  for _ in range(root_parent_level):
    root = root.parent
    full_pkg = f"{root.name}.{full_pkg}"
    MODULE_PATH = f"{root}{pathlib.os.path.sep}__init__.py"
    MODULE_NAME = f"{root.name}"
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(MODULE_NAME, MODULE_PATH)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[spec.name] = module 
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  __package__ = full_pkg
```