# Importing from python modules inside parent directory into jupyter notebook files inside subdirectory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import, python-module

I have a file structure like this:

```
project_folder/
     notebooks/
          notebook01.ipynb
          notebook02.ipynb
          ...
          notebookXY.ipynb
     module01.py
     module02.py
     module03.py
```

In `.ipynb` files inside `notebook/` folder I want to import classes and functions from `module01.py, module02.py` and `module03.py`.

I have found answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478398/import-local-function-from-a-module-housed-in-another-directory-with-relative-im) that it is possible using following lines of code inside every notebook and run those lines as first cell every time:

```
import os
import sys
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
```

Is there please a better way for this? What if I have A LOT of `.ipynb` files inside `notebooks/` folder, do I have to paste those lines of code at the beginning of every single one? Is there a better, more minimalist or cleaner way?

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to move all your Python modules (.py files) into a folder and make them an installable package. If you `pip` install it into your current environment, you can then import the package into any notebook in that environment, regardless of folder structure.

So in your situation you could have:

```
project_folder/
  notebooks/
    notebook01.ipynb
    notebook02.ipynb
    ...
    notebookXY.ipynb
  my_package/
    __init__.py
    module01.py
    module02.py
    module03.py
  setup.py
```

- *__init__.py* can just be an empty file, and tells Python "everything in this folder is part of a package"
- For an explanation of what goes in *setup.py* see [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-setup-py).

A basic *setup.py* can be as simple as this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="my_package",
    version="0.0.1",
    description="A small example package",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    python_requires='>=3.7',
)
```

Install it:

```
cd project_folder
pip install [-e] .
```

Including the optional `-e` flag will install *my_package* in "editable" mode, meaning that instead of copying the files into your virtual environment, a symlink will be created to the files where they are.

Now in any notebook you can do:

`import my_package`

Or

`from my_package.module01 import <some object>`

Comment: You should put the setup.py file as well in the my_package folder. In my case, it couldn't find the necessary files within the folder. If it is in the same folder it works perfectelly. Thanks a lot. Very helpful.

Comment: Hi this is a really useful answer however when I try and install my_package in the same set up as above from one of the notebooks (notebook01.ipynb) it won't work since the working directory is in notebooks and not the parent project_folder. Is there a way to deal with this nicely? I.e. so all notebooks are created with the working directory set to project_folder or other solution?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the `project_folder` to your [`PYTHONPATH` environment variable.](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH) This will allow you to tell python to search that directory for imports.

You would do this in your user profile settings, or in your startup script - not in python. It's something that has to be set before python ever gets run.

Comment: how can I do this please?

Comment: How are you running the `ipynb` files? From a command line, by clicking with a mouse, something else?

Comment: clicking in Jupyter Notebook, I can do it by running cell with code:
`sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))` but it does not solve my problem permanently, just until I restart kernel, it's almost the same as original solution in my Q body

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu

Comment: Try doing `export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/path/to/project_folder:$PYTHONPATH"` in your ~/.profile file. (Google returns a lot of hits for this.)