# Importing functions into Jupyter Notebook getting a name error

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working Jupyter notebook on AWS Sagemaker instance. For convenience I wrote a .py file with couple of functions as defined;

```
#function to gather the percent of acts in each label feature combo

def compute_pct_accts(data, label_cnt):
"""
data is the output from aggregate_count
labe_cnt gives the breakdown of data for each target value
"""

label_data_combined = pd.merge(data, label_cnt, how='inner', left_on= 'label', right_on = 'label')
label_data_combined['Act_percent'] = np.round((label_data_combined['ACT_CNT']/label_data_combined['Total_Cnt'])*100,2)
return label_data_combined


#write a function to perform aggregation for target and feature column

def aggregate_count(df, var, target):

"""
df is the dataframe,
var is the feature name
target is the label varaible(0 or 1)
"""

label_var_cnt = df.groupby([var,target],observed=True)['ID'].count()
label_var_cnt = label_var_cnt.reset_index()
label_var_cnt.rename(columns={'ID':'ACT_CNT'},inplace=True)
return label_var_cnt
```

Both these functions are stored in a .py file called file1.py. Then to retrieve them in my notebook I typed;

```
from file1 import *
import pandas as pd
```

This command did import both functions. But when I tried to run the function;

```
compute_pct_accts(GIACT_Match_label_cnt, label_cnt)
```

I am getting a Name error;

```
pd not found
```

Please note that I have imported pandas as pd in my jupyter notebook.  I am aware of using the option

```
%run -i compute_pct_accts_new.py
```

but that forces me to write a new python file with that function. My question is, can we have one python file with all functions defined in it, so that we can import all of them at once and use interactively in notebook.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: No, you need to import `pandas` in your `file1.py` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try importing pandas in the .py file containing the function you want to import.

Comment: Appreciate your reply. I did adding `import pandas as pd` in the python file as advised. But the error is still the same `name pd is not defined`.

Comment: Check out this post: hhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/54725559
Maybe you can create a module containing the functions you need and install it in your environment. Then you'd import them from said module