# Importing Python modules to Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook

I have got the next hierarchy:

```
project_name
|-utils
| |-lib
|   |-module.py
|-notebooks
| |-nb.ipynb
```

How can I import module.py to the np.ipynb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import local function from a module housed in another directory with relative imports in Jupyter Notebook using Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478398/import-local-function-from-a-module-housed-in-another-directory-with-relative-im)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sys` package as follows on `nb.ipynb`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/path/to/module.py")
```