# Jupyter crashes when running imported function from another .py file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm working on a research project that involves detecting hand gestures with WiFi CSI data. I basically have to record samples and then select the 20-packet-long interval during which the gesture occurs. I'm writing a script using `ipywidgets` to display the original spectrogram, ask for the first index of the sequence, show cropped spectrogram, and ask for confirmation before writing the clean data to a file.
The script is imported from a `.py` file to an `ipynb` notebook where the prompts will show.

The problem is that every time I run the imported `cleaner` function, the kernel crashes. This happens both on a local machine and Google Colab.

Here's all the relevant code:

```py
# data_cleaner.py

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csiread # exports csv directly from pcap file!!
import ipywidgets as widgets # --> user interaction in Jupyter
from IPython.display import clear_output, display

def cleaner(csifile, gesture_length):
    # Extract csi directly from pcap file
    print('testing...') # not even this runs...
    csifile = '/content/REU/csi samples/csi_palmfist_1.pcap'
    csidata = csiread.Nexmon(csifile, chip='4339', bw=20)
    csidata.read()
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(csidata.csi)
    
    magMatrix = df1.applymap(abs) # magnitude matrix
    
    # define the useless subcarriers
    garbage = [1, 0, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38] # 14 removed
    
    cleaned = df1.drop(garbage, axis = 1)
    # display(cleaned)
    
    # amplitude visualization
    magMatrix = cleaned.applymap(np.abs)
    subcarLineChart(magMatrix)
    subcarSpectrogram(magMatrix)
    
    # smoothen the magnitude chart
    # apply is essentially map but passes each row instead of each element
    magSmoothened = magMatrix.apply(lambda x: mov_avg(x, 3))
    subcarLineChart(magSmoothened)
    subcarSpectrogram(magSmoothened)
    
    
    # UI STARTS HERE
    # limit useful gesture length to predefined value
    
    start_index = widgets.Text(
        value = '',
        description = 'Index for first packet in {}-packet sequence containing gesture:'.format(length)
        )
    extract_btn = widgets.Button(
        desciption = 'Extract'
        )
    
    extract_btn.on_click(handle_extract)
    
    # START = 
    
    # crop selected interval
    # btw: mag means magnitude
    # magSelected = magSmoothened[START:(START+LENGTH)]
    
    # show selected interval
    # subcarLineChart(magSelected)
    # subcarSpectrogram(magSelected)
    

## UI LOGIC
def handle_extract():
    magSelected = magSmoothened[START:(START+LENGTH)]
    subcarLineChart(magSelected)
    subcarSpectrogram(magSelected)
    
    display("Does this match what you were trying to extract? \n    If not, re-run the program. (ctrl-f9 on windows)\n")
    confirm_btn = widgets.Button(
        description = 'Yes, looks good'
        )
    confirm_btn.on_click(handle_confirm)
    
def handle_confirm():
    print('writes to file...')

## VISUALIZATION FUNCTIONS
from matplotlib import colors

def subcarLineChart(gph, log = False): # log: use log scale or not
    packet_index = len(gph.index)
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.title("Magnitude of Signal by Channel and Packet Number")
    plt.xlabel("Packet #")
    plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
    ax1.set_yscale("log") if log else None
    
    num_subcarriers = len(gph.columns)
    num_samples = len(gph)
    for subcar_index in range(num_subcarriers):
        ax1.plot(
            range(num_samples),
            gph.iloc[:,subcar_index],
            lw = .25,
            label = subcar_index
        )
    
    plt.show()

def subcarSpectrogram(gph, log = False, subcar_start = 0, subcar_end = -1): # log: use log scale or not
    subcar_end = len(gph.iloc[0]) if subcar_end == -1 else subcar_end # replace -1 with valid final index
    plt.imshow(
    gph,
    # extent --> left, rigth, bottom, top
    extent = (subcar_start, subcar_end, len(gph), 0),
    norm = colors.LogNorm() if log else None)
    plt.xlabel('Subcarriers')
    plt.ylabel('Packet #')
    plt.colorbar(
      label = 'intensity')
    
    plt.show()
    
def mov_avg(arr, width):
    return np.convolve(arr, np.ones(width), 'valid') / width
```

```py
# interactive data cleaning.ipynb
!pip install csiread

from google.colab import drive
import sys
drive.mount('/AshkanDrive')
!ln -s '/AshkanDrive/MyDrive/google_colab_files_for_CSI' '/content/REU'
filepath = '/content/REU/csi samples/old_testing_data/csi_palmfist_1.pcap'

sys.path.insert(0, '/content/REU/utils/')
from data_cleaner import cleaner

cleaner(filepath, 20) # 20 packets should be fine to fit all gestures
```

Comment: Is this relevant; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478398/import-local-function-from-a-module-housed-in-another-directory-with-relative-im ?